# Enable H.264 (or x264) in AVIDemux

Tags: macos, video, mp4, h.264, avidemux

I am trying to get AVIDemux set up with the X264 codec using [this](http://shiftpop.blogspot.com/2008/09/compiling-x264-with-mp4-support-on-os-x.html) tutorial. The following is what goes down when I get to the `./configure --enable-mp4-output` command

```
Thomas-Phillipss-MacBook:x264 tomdabomb2u$ sudo ./configure --enable-mp4-output
Password:
Unknown option --enable-mp4-output, ignored
Found no assembler
Minimum version is yasm-0.6.2
If you really want to compile without asm, configure with --disable-asm.
```

So I tried it.

```
Thomas-Phillipss-MacBook:x264 tomdabomb2u$ sudo ./configure --enable-mp4-output --disable-asm
Unknown option --enable-mp4-output, ignored
Warning: gpac is too old, update to 2007-06-21 UTC or later
Platform:   X86_64
System:     MACOSX
asm:        no
avs:        no
lavf:       no
ffms:       no
gpac:       no
pthread:    yes
filters:    crop select_every
debug:      no
gprof:      no
PIC:        no
shared:     no
visualize:  no
bit depth:  8

You can run 'make' or 'make fprofiled' now.
```

I issued `make`, and then `Thomas-Phillipss-MacBook:x264 tomdabomb2u$ ./x264 -v -q 20 -o foreman.mp4 foreman_part_qcif.yuv 176x144`. And as expected, the results are:

```
x264 [error]: not compiled with MP4 output support
```

So I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There's also [a Bash script](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Avidemux/Avidemux_2.6_script_MacOSX_10.6.8) to build `avidemux +aac+dts+lame+ogg+x264+xvid (Avidemux 2.6 (SVN revision 7891)` using MacPorts.

Answer (score 0):

```
Unknown option --enable-mp4-output, ignored
```

That immediately caught my attention. Sounds like the sources you downloaded may not be the same ones the guide writer was using. Also, did the git checkout work successfully?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to get it installed via MacPorts today. I actually installed ffmpeg (`sudo ports install ffmpeg`), and I think x264 was included in the install. I still do not see the option in AVIDemux though :-\